# WiFi problem after 4.3.2 jailbreak

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, wifi, unlock

I've just jailbroken my iPhone (3Gs, 5.13.04, iOS 4.3.2, Pwnage Tool 4.3.2).

Now I'm experiencing troubles with WiFi, so I can't do an unlock. I have an AirPort Express router, it works well with other devices, the iPhone does have connection with the router (in the Settings -> Wifi menu there is a checkmark in front of my network) but there is no indication of WiFi connection and none of my applications see this connection.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, it is not pretty clear, but it works.

First, I've rebooted my router

Second, in `Settings -> General -> Network` I've set `Cellular Data` and `Enable 3G` to OFF. After that operation WiFi indicator appeared and everything went well.

Hope it helps to those who experience the same problem.